# Как типизировать forwardRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Имеется такой компонент:

```typescript
import { forwardRef, Ref } from "react";

export interface ICelebrationScreenProps
{
    title: string;
    [ prop: string ]: any;
}

function CelebrationScreen({ title, ...props }: ICelebrationScreenProps, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>)
{
    return (<>{title}</>);
};

export default forwardRef(CelebrationScreen);
```

Когда я пытаюсь использовать данный компонент в другом файле, VSCode мне не дает подсказок и ошибок о пропсах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если же я буду использовать компонент без forwardRef, допустим таким способом, то я получу необходимые мне ошибки:

```typescript
import { forwardRef, Ref } from "react";

export interface ICelebrationScreenProps
{
    title: string;
    [ prop: string ]: any;
}

function CelebrationScreen({ title, ...props }: ICelebrationScreenProps, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>)
{
    return (<>{title}</>);
};

export default forwardRef(CelebrationScreen);

function Test()
{
    return <CelebrationScreen />
}
```

[image]

> Свойство "title" отсутствует в типе "{}" и является обязательным в типе "ICelebrationScreenProps". ts(2741)

Вы также можете увидеть это поведение на

[image: Edit wonderful-rubin-lvnwpr]

Comment: Вы интересные люди, ставите минус не обосновав его. Что вам вечно не нравится? Код есть, скриншоты есть..

Comment: на форуме следует отправлять код  текстовом формате

Comment: Вы не видите код в текстовом формате?

Comment: вижу, а также вижу скриншоты с кодом

Comment: И что запрещает мне прикладывать скриншоты, где видно поведение редактора?

Comment: это правило форума - код в текстовом виде. Редактор как правило предупреждает, что отправлять код следует именно таким образом

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11865/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: В вопросе представлен как код, так и скриншот. Что вас не устраивает то?

Comment: в вашем случае код и ошибки на скриншотах было бы удобнее воспринимать как текст

Comment: или у вас и код и скриншот это одно и тоже?

Comment: Не считаю, что данную ошибку стоило выносить в вопрос.

Comment: И по первой ссылочке дойдите до раздела `4. Меры` и почитайте внимательно.

Comment: я не ставил минус на ваш вопрос)

Comment: Вообще нифига не понял. [mcve] делай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил ссылку на CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы наиболее гибко использовать типизацию можно завести определенный интерфейс `ForwardRefExoticComponent` ([подробнее](https://use-form.netlify.app/interfaces/_node_modules__types_react_index_d_.react.forwardrefexoticcomponent.html)):

```
import { forwardRef, ReactElement, Ref, WeakValidationMap } from "react";

interface ForwardRefExoticComponent<P> {
  (props: P): ReactElement | null;
  readonly $$typeof: symbol;
  displayName?: string;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
}
```

**Сам интерфейс `ForwardRefExoticComponent` можно не прописывать, а импортировать из реакта.**

```
import { ForwardRefExoticComponent } from "react";
```

Далее мы сможем использовать его подобным образом, типизируя под конкретные пропсы и получать подстветку ошибки в JSX:

```
const CelebrationScreenWithRef: ForwardRefExoticComponent<ICelebrationScreenProps> = forwardRef(
  CelebrationScreen
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): 
// ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;

const CelebrationScreen = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, CelebrationScreenProps>(
({ title }, ref) => {
return (
    <div ref={ref}>{title}</div>
   );
  },
 );
```

Comment: Чем ваш ответ решает проблему?